# Religious appearance

Tags: sentence-request

In my mother language, there is a proverb which says: "Religious appearance is no a sign of being a religious person at all"; I've found two sentences in a local dictionary of proverbs and colloquialism. I would be thankful if you let me know which one sounds more natural to you in American English:

> 1. Religious appearance doesn’t equate to a pious man.
> 2. If the beard were all, the goat might preach.

Comment: I really like #2, but I would use the indefinite article before _goat_: _If the beard were all, a goat might preach._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your sentences are understandable.

Your second sentence might sound better as

> If *a* beard were all, *a* goat might preach.
>   *if a beard was the only thing necessary, a goat might preach*

Your first sentence is more general, however your second sentence might only work for certain orthodox religions.

Comment: Actually, the *goat* sentence communicates well and *can* work more generally, in the same way that "All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy." works even for people not called Jack, and for non-boys.